# Getting Segmentation fault while searching in a file

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a code for a simple database which holds information of type "info".

Here's my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define NAME_LENGTH 20
#define EMAIL_LENGTH 15

struct info {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char email[EMAIL_LENGTH];
    int flag;
};

int createDB(char *name) {
    FILE * file = fopen(name, "w+b");
    return fclose(file);
}

FILE *openDB(char *name) {
    FILE* file = fopen(name, "r+b");
    if(file != NULL) return file;
    return NULL;
}

int closeDB(FILE *f) {
    return fclose(f);
}

struct info *get(FILE *file, int index) {
    struct info* temp;
    fseek(file, index*sizeof(struct info), SEEK_SET);
    fread(temp, 1, sizeof(struct info), file);
    if(feof(file) != 0) return NULL;
    return temp;

}

int put(FILE *file, int index, struct info *record) {
    fseek(file, index*sizeof(struct info), SEEK_SET);
    int res = fwrite(record, 1, sizeof(struct info), file);
    if(res) return 0;
    else return EOF;
}

struct info *search(FILE *file, char *name) {
    int k = 0;
    struct info* temp = get(file, 0);
    do {

        if(temp -> flag == 1 && strcmp(temp -> name,name) == 0) return temp;
        k++;
        temp = get(file, k);

    }while(temp != NULL);

    return temp;
}
```

When I "put", "get" information from a file, everything is working fine. But, when I try to search according to name, I am getting **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** error.

Could you, please, you show my mistake here?

Comment: did you try any debugging tool? try gdb, it's good.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux, which has a [nice documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) with tutorial material).

Comment: Also, don't forget to pass `-Wall` (and perhaps even also `-Wextra`) - in addition to `-g` to get debugging information -  to `gcc` (or `g++`), it will help you a lot if you improve your code till no warnings are given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
struct info* temp;
...
fread(temp, 1, sizeof(struct info), file);
```

in `get` tries to write `sizeof(struct info)` bytes to the uninitialised pointer `temp`.  You need to allocate memory for `temp`.

The easiest way to do this may be to modify the signature of `get` to allow callers to use an `info` instance from their stack

```
int get(FILE *file, int index, struct info *record) {
    fseek(file, index*sizeof(*record), SEEK_SET);
    fread(record, 1, sizeof(*record), file);
    if(feof(file) != 0) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

which could be called like

```
struct info record;
if (get(file, 0, &record) == -1) {
    /* eof */
}
```